# Tool that records USB device attaches and detaches

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, usb

Background:

When my PC goes into some sort of energy saving mode, the monitor is black and I can't have a look at things. In this state, I can hear that one or more USB devices attach and detach in regular intervals, since Windows plays the sounds.

Request:

I'm looking for a tool that records the USB devices that attach and detach. It must not only show that information while the event is occuring but record a history to be reviewed at a later point in time. It should be able to identify the device uniquely, ideally with vendor and device name, so I can find it in hardware.

The tool must work on Windows 7 and not require an Internet connection. It should be gratis.

I don't need a tool that captures USB traffic.